# React Native Drawer Navigation not working

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to React Native so I am having this problem of Drawer Navigation not Working. I have downloaded all the dependenciese, but whenever I run the code I get a giant blank page. I also get an error on the terminal that says:

ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module RCTEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling receiveTouches). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

The Drawer Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Pressable,
    TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>This is Home</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const Settings = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>This is Settings</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerTab = () => {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings}/>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    )
}



export default DrawerTab;
```

App File
/**
* Sample React Native App
* https://github.com/facebook/react-native
*
* @format
* @flow strict-local
*/

```
 import 'react-native-gesture-handler'; //The documentation on the drawer webpage says this should before anything in the entry file
    import React from 'react';
    import DrawerTab from './project/drawerComp';
    
const App = () => {
    return (
    <DrawerTab />
  );
};
```

All other Navigations (Stack, BottomTab/BottomMaterial, TopTab etc...) have worked perfectly fine except for the drawer navigation.

Thank you.

Comment: Enclose your drawer in `NavigationContainer`.

Comment: @Rohit I did that but still the same error with blank page. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share GitHub link or snack to your code? The above code snippet worked for me.

Comment: Okay here is the github link https://github.com/Misbahoo/DrawerNavigation I just created. Thank you. By the way, are you using android or iOS? Because I am using android.

Comment: I tested on iOS Simulator.

Comment: I think the issue might be on android then

Comment: I have added PR to your repo.

Comment: Okay thank you man. I will run it and see if it works.

Comment: I run it but still the same error with blank page. I am lost actually.

Comment: You need to run `cd android` and then `./gradlew clean`. Also uninstall the previous application before running application again.

Comment: I cloned the repo as new application and it worked. I did not even had to run the `./gradlew clean`. Thank you so much man. But please may I know what you did that fixed the issue? I can see the changes on the repo but I don't know why? Thank you once again.

Comment: You had not added the dependencies for drawer navigation like `react-native-screens`. Also you're missing the changes to be needed in Android like `build.gradle` and `MainApplication.java`.